# I want the number to disappear when the countdown reaches 1 "the 2 being the last number to show". The countdown needs to continue to count until -1

Tags: javascript, html, css, countdown

How can I get this countdown to hide the numbers after the countdown reaches 1. The 2 is the last number I want to show. The countdown needs to continue to count all the way to -1, just not show up on the screen. The images will do the rest. I've been trying to get this to work, so I'm using a fairly simple counter. When I get everything working the way I want, I'm going to change the counter to a countdown clock that uses the users date and time and time zone to count down to a date I put into the countdown. Thanks for all your help.

Here is the link to the fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/trino98/db4086xn/50/

```js
function getImg(num) {
  var digits = String(num).split(""),
text = "";
  // Getting the path to the numbers
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
text += '<img alt="' + digits[i] + '" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/' + digits[i] + '.png" class="digits"/>';
  }
  return text;
}

// Images to change to
var oneDaySrc = function() {
  document.getElementById("image").src = "https://okoutdoors.com/img/halloween-oneday.gif";
}
var duringSrc = function() {
  document.getElementById("image").src = "https://okoutdoors.com/img/halloween-during.gif";
}
var afterSrc = function() {
  document.getElementById("image").src = "https://okoutdoors.com/img/catandmoonl.jpg";
}

// Change the image as the count down counts down
var count = 5;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  count = count - 1;
  if (count == 1) {
oneDaySrc();
  } else if (count == 0) {
duringSrc();
  } else if (count < 0) {
clearInterval(counter);
afterSrc();
  }
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = getImg(count);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}

.imageOne {
  width: 40%;
  transform: translate(74%, 00%);
}

.imageTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 123.5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
  width: 12%;
  height: auto;
}

.digits {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" class="imageOne" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/halloween-before.gif">
<br>
<div><span class="imageTwo" id="timer"></span></div>
```

If I tell it to clearInterval in the "if" or first "else if" statement it stops the counter. I need it to hide the number, but keep counting. I need it to clearInterval or stop counting at -1.

Comment: This is not Java. Use tags correctly.

Comment: if count == 1, then you should change the `display` style to `hidden`.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but "When I get everything working the way I want, I'm going to change the counter to a countdown clock that uses the users date and time and time zone to count down to a date I put into the countdown.": this is not a good way of doing a countdown if it has to match a real-time clock. You cannot assume that one second has passed after a one second delay. (If someone's using Firefox, and they put their computer into sleep mode; or if their computer's laggy; or any number of other reasons.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question, you can change `getImg` to return a black pixel (instead of a digit) when the count is less than one. Like,

```js
function getImg(num) {
  if (num < 1) {
      return "<img src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/make-github-pseudonymous-again/pixels/main/1x1%23000000.png' class='digits' />";
  }
  var digits = String(num).split(""),
    text = "";
  // Getting the path to the numbers
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    text += '<img alt="' + digits[i] + '" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/' + digits[i] + '.png" class="digits"/>';
  }
  return text;
}

// Images to change to
var oneDaySrc = function() {
  document.getElementById("image").src = "https://okoutdoors.com/img/halloween-oneday.gif";
}
var duringSrc = function() {
  document.getElementById("image").src = "https://okoutdoors.com/img/halloween-during.gif";
}
var afterSrc = function() {
  document.getElementById("image").src = "https://okoutdoors.com/img/catandmoonl.jpg";
}

// Change the image as the count down counts down
var count = 5;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  count = count - 1;
  if (count == 1) {
    oneDaySrc();
  } else if (count == 0) {
    duringSrc();
  } else if (count < 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
    afterSrc();
  }
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = getImg(count);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h1.u-center {
  font-family: serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.10em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #254441;
  font-style: italic;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ff5f04;
}

.catAndMoon {
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.image {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}

.imageOne {
  width: 40%;
  transform: translate(74%, 00%);
}

.imageTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 123.5%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
  width: 12%;
  height: auto;
}

.digits {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image Countdown</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="u-center">Image Countdown</h1>

  <hr class="1">

  <p align="center">
    <img class="catAndMoon" src="https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/catandmoonr.jpg" alt="Happy">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/hallo_spooky.jpg" alt="Happy Halloween">
    <img class="catAndMoon" src="https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/catandmoonr.jpg" alt="Halloween">
  </p>

  <p align="center">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/darkjack.gif" style="width:25%" alt="Spooky">
  </p>

  <!-- <div id="newcountdown"></div> -->

  <img id="image" class="imageOne" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/halloween-before.gif">
  <br>
  <div><span class="imageTwo" id="timer"></span></div>

</body>

</html>
```